# could someone explain to me this CodeForces 919B/Perfect Number solution?

Tags: c++

This is a solution I found to CodeForces problem 919B - Perfect Number.
I technically understand what it is doing but I want to understand the 'intuition' behind it or the idea/approach.

```
int main(){
    int k=0, m=19, c=0, sum=0;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    while(true){
        int n = m;
        sum = 0;
        while(n){
            sum+=n%10;
            n=n/10;
        }
        printf("%d %d %d\n", n, sum, c);
        if(sum == 10) c++;
        if(c == k) break;
        m++;
    }
    printf("%d", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whenever a perfect number is found (sum of its digits is 10) we increment `c`. When `c == k` we have found the kth perfect number.

Comment: That code should fail to compile...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt why? It compiles fine on both GCC and Clang with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Then either those compilers are broken or you don't compile that code with them. Both `scanf` and `printf` are symbols that are not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User 0x499602D2 already gave a very concise answer, but let me elaborate a bit. A super-high-level pseudo code would look like this:

```
loop over natural numbers and check if they are perfect:
  if found k such numbers: 
    stop and output the last perfect number
```

Here's a more detailed pseudo-code that matches your piece of c++ code:

```
m   = 19 # first perfect number (1+9=10) - a good starting point
c   = 0  # total number of perfect numbers found so far
sum = 0  # temporary variable that will hold the sum of digits

read k from stdin # we're going to look for the k-th perfect number 

# we start an open-ended search but we know that we will find k-th number and stop
for m = 19 ... infinity:
  if m is perfect:
    increment c by one        # found c perfect numbers so far

  if c == k:           
    exit loop and return m    # m is the k-th perfect number! we're done!
```

See how `c` corresponds to the number of the "perfect numbers" we've found? Once `c` hits `k`, our loop can stop.

One more technical bit: how do we check if the number 1945 is perfect? We need to sum the digits: 1+9+4+5. A simple way to get the least significant digit from a number `n` is to take the remainder of the division by 10 (i.e. `n modulo 10`):

```
1945 % 10 = 5
194  % 10 = 4
19   % 10 = 9
1    % 10 = 1
```

How to get from 1945 to 194 to 19 to 1? Just do integer division by 10:

```
1945/10 = 194
 194/10 = 19
  19/10 = 1
   1/10 = 0 -> stop the loop, since while(0) is the same as while(false)
```

That's what's happening before `printf`.